# Do we need implicit base 10 in order to represent a number in any given base?

Tags: notation, philosophy, foundations

We have been thought to notate a number n in base b as such,  :
e.g. 23 in base 10 $23_{10} =23$ , $3_2=11$ , n in base b as $n_b$

My problem is that both the number (n) and base (b) are written implicitly in base 10. is it possible to write the representation without using implicit base 10 , without ambiguity?

e.g. instead of $3_2$ to write $11_{10}$ without ambiguity? As motivation to this question, how can we be sure that $23_{10}$ is not actually what we consider as $23_7$ and $10_7$ (what ever the number 23 in base 7 is , and 10 in base 7 (i.e. 7 in base 10).

Comment: Instead of $23_{10}$ we can write $\text{Twenty-three}_\text{Ten}$ or $\text{XXIII}_\text{X}$.

Comment: @MJD intrestingly made me realise romans did not use base notation.

Comment: Or you can do $SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSZ_{SSSSSSSSSSZ}$.

Comment: @MJD : but it seems we still have to all agree on basis being used first! same as righ and left.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need an implicit basis $10$, but we must write the number using the correct digits and the correct  indication of the basis and, usually, this is done writing the base in base ten.

Your $3_2=11$ is wrong (there is not the symbol $3$ in base $2$). The correct way is $3_{10}=11_2$, or $3_{ten}=11_{two}$.

Comment: $11_2$ is wrong too, it should be $11_{10}$, thank you

Comment: Thank you! I added to my answer.